# compare two arrays with array_search -

Tags: php, arrays

```html
$a2=[1,7,3,4,8,9];
$a=[1,7,3,4,8,9];
for($i=0; $i<6 ;$i++){
    if (array_search($a2[$i],$a)){
        echo "Yes","<br>", $a2[$i];
    }else{
            echo "No","<br>", $a2[$i];
    }
}
```

Why the output is not equal?
No
1Yes
7Yes
3Yes
4Yes
8Yes
9

Answer (score 1):

As per php document:

> array_search — Searches the array for a given value and returns the
> first corresponding key if successful

so your first value is `0` which is interpreted as `false` which is why it prints `No`

Comment: Yes it is true, but how can I make a peer-to-peer comparison between two arrays?

Comment: You can check  array_intersect() function

Comment: @Netman9297 you can also do `false !== array_search($a2[$i],$a)`

Answer (score 1):

Using **in_array($a, $a2)** will return a boolean instead of the key value.

```
$a2=[1,7,3,4,8,9];
$a=[1,7,3,4,8,9,12];
for($i=0; $i<7 ;$i++){
    echo $a2[$i], "\n";
    echo $a[$i], "\n";
    if (in_array($a2[$i],$a)){
        echo "Yes";
    }else{
        echo "No";   }
}
```